# Can you assign two buttons to trigger animations to one element in CSS?

Tags: css, animation, checkbox, label

I need a wide div or table divided in three tds. The middle one is visible (which I achieved by putting it into another div with overflow:hidden and absolute positioning within relative positioning). The middle section also contains two buttons. What I need is when we click on the first one, the whole div or table should move right to reveal the left section. The other button should make the whole thing move right to reveal the left section.

I tried to make them labels of a checkbox and later add:

```css
input#en:checked + div#bodywrapperfloat {
   animation: enslide 1s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

but nothing moves (the checkbox checks though). The animation should make it move, but it doesn't. I think the reason might be that the labels are actually inside the moving div. Is this a problem? Can you suggest any other CSS solution?

In short, I need an element that moves left or right depending on the button clicked.

I'm adding some code I tried to use with the table:

```css
#bodywrapperfixed {
width: 1440px;
margin: 0px auto;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 730px;
}


#bodywrapperfloat {
width: 4320px;
border: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: -1440px;
table-layout:fixed;
color: #000;
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

table#ramka {
width: 4320px;
border: none;
table-layout:fixed;
color: #000;
border: none;
}


table#ramka td{
width: 1440px;
border: none;
}

table#linki {
width: 110px;
border: none;
margin-top:15px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: #117D10;
  text-align: center;
  padding:23px;

}

label:hover {
  background-color: #004F00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input#pl {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}

input#en {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

animation:

```css
@keyframes enslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes enslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes enslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:0px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes enslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:0px;}
}

@-o-keyframes enslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:0px;}
}


@keyframes plslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:-2880px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes plslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:-2880px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes plslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:-2880px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes plslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:-2880px;}
}

@-o-keyframes plslide
{
from {left:-1440px;}
to {left:-2880px;}
}


input#en:checked + div#bodywrapperfloat {


     animation: enslide 1s;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;

     -webkit-animation: enslide 1s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

     -moz-animation: enslide 1s; 
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

     -ms-animation: enslide 1s; 
     -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

     -o-animation: enslide 1s; 
     -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="bodywrapperfixed">
<div id="bodywrapperfloat">
<table id="ramka">
     <tr>
          <td>left td</td>
          <td>center td

<table id="linki">
<tr>
<td><label for="en">en</label><input id="en" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><label for="pl">pl</label><input id="pl" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr></table>
</center>
</div></td>
          <td>right td</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use CSS only, input checked shoul be ahead of table in the flow of document, same level or lower-lewel.

Selector will be basicly:

```
:checked ~ table {
/* adjacent table further in the flow will receive style*/
}
:checked ~ div table {
/* adjacent div  further in the flow will send style to its table child */
}
```

Comment: so does that mean the buttons (labels posing as buttons to be exact) cannot be put inside of the table I want to animate?

Comment: Not yet , CSS c for cascade. For the moment you have no selector in CSS abble to climb up the HTML tree :) CSS level 4 promised to. If you want to keep input inside table, it will be js option. But if you just keep correct labels inside and inputs outside table, it should work.